# QEMU guest internet access

Tags: qemu

I have read many documentation and threads but could not figure out how to allow the guest machine to access the internet.

Below is the command for creating the guest Alpine Linux machine on MacOS x86_64 (Ventura 13.2.1)

```shell
$ qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -M virt \
  -m 4096 \
  -rtc base=utc,clock=host,driftfix=slew \
  -bios QEMU_EFI.fd \
  -device virtio-rng-pci \
  -device virtio-balloon \
  -nographic \
  -no-reboot \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -drive if=virtio,file=user-data.qcow2 \
  -monitor unix:monitor.sock,server,nowait \
  -netdev user,id=net1,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:10022-:22 \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net1 \
  -smp 4 \
  -cdrom boot.iso \
  -drive if=virtio,file=tmp.qcow2 \
  -cpu cortex-a72
```

And within the guest, this is the network output

```shell
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          LOOPBACK  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network unreachable
```

What should be done to make the guest machine reach the internet?
Would appreciate if I could see 2 types of networking:

1. Have the guest with a dedicate IP address, were the host operating system could interact with the guest using the guest IP address
2. Have the guest just access the internet, whether it is a bridge or NAT

Thanks

Comment: What OS is the guest running, and how would you configure its networking if it were a physical machine?

Comment: @user1686 I've updated the post with answers. MacOS and bridged/NAT